# Can constant C always be positive?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I was given an equation $dA/dt = 2A$, where $A(0) = 9$.
I had managed to solve it and managed to get the correct answer but I got confused looking through it later because I had allowed my constant to be positive as I had thought that a negative number would make my $c$ a negative number, if that makes sense..?

My working goes like this:

Integrate $\frac1{2A}\,dA$ = $dt$
which gives:

$\frac12 \ln(A)+C = t+C$.

Now if I move $C$ to the RHS, $C$ would then be a positive/negative number, but I went with positive giving me the correct answer.

If C was negative the next few steps would be:

$A = e^{2t - c}$ (I can't format this properly)

Plugging in $A = 9$ and $t= 2$, $C$ would then equals to $-9$ which is not correct since $\ln(-9)$ is undefined. But I was wondering how $C$ would apply in other situations where it could be positive or negative. How would I know what sign $C$ would have?

Comment: $C$ doesn't need a sign assignment, it's an unspecified constant until you solve for it.  Also, there isn't any place in your working for arriving at $\ln(-9)$... can you clarify how you got that quantity?

Comment: $e^{-c}=9$ leads to $c=-\ln(9)$.

Comment: No, you don't get $\tfrac12 \ln(A) + C = t+C$, you get $\tfrac12 \ln|A| = t+C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of $c$ doesn't matter because to get the solution of the differential equation you take
$e^c$ which is always positive.

Comment: Yes, in this equation the sign doesn't matter but what about in other scenarios? taking the integration would provide a C, $C_1$ , on one side and $C_2$ on the other side. Assuming that $C_1$ is bigger than $C_2$, then that would cause the final constant to be either negative or positive. Which one should I go with? Eg. $x$ + $C_1$ = 4 + $C_2$. Moving $C_1$ to the RHS and subtracting it from $C_2$ will give out another constant, which I'm going to call B. What sign should B be then since either signs will give out a different number. Hope that makes sense!